# What Bracha do you make on an acai bowl?

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, shehakol-beracha

What Bracha do you make on an acai bowl?

These bowls usually contain yogurt, berries, and granola.

Here is a link for reference: [Acai Bowl](https://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/food-network-kitchen/acai-breakfast-bowl-3363448)

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Harvey and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Maybe they usually contain yogurt, but the one you link to contains none (but has açai purée, which you don't list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you eat each food separately, you would make separate blessings on the berries (*ha'eitz* for acai or blueberries which grow from a tree, but strawberries and wild berries would be *ha'adama*, see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/61248/11501)), granola (*ha'adama*, cf [here](http://dinonline.org/2011/11/04/berachah-on-granola/), if not said on the berries already) and yoghurt (*shehakol*), in that order.

If you eat the yoghurt as a mixture, the rules of *ikar* (main) and *tafel* (secondary) come into play (see [here](http://www.aish.com/jl/jewish-law/blessings/20-Primary-and-Secondary-Foods.html)). This means one says the blessing on the main ingredient, in this case the yoghurt, which is *sheakol*. But you enter into doubtful territory if the berries are granola are not well mixed/incorporated into the yoghurt. If there is less yoghurt, you could argue the other way around, that the berries are granola are the *ikar* and the *yoghurt* doesn't need its own blessing. The safest halachic aproach is therefore the the first above.

As always, [CYLOR](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146) before applying anything *halachic* you read on the Internet.